# How exactly Apache Nifi ConsumeKafka_1_0 processor works

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-nifi

I have Nifi cluster of and Kafka is also installed there.

Created one topic with 5 partitions, start consuming that topic with one gourp-id. So that each partition will get unique messages.

Now I created the 5 ConsumeKafka_1_0 processors having the intent of getting unique messages on each consumer side. But only 2 of the ConsumeKafka_1_0 are consuming all the messages rest is setting ideal.

Now what I did is started the 5 command line Kafka consumer, and what happened is, I was able to see the all the partitions are getting the messages and able to consume them from command line consumer in round-robin fashion only.

Also, I tried descried the Kafka group and what I saw was only 2 of the Nifi ConsumeKafka_1_0 is consuming all the 5 partitions and rest is ideal, see the snapshot.

[image]

Would you please let me what I am doing wrong here with Nifi consumer processor.

Note - i used Nifi version is 1.5 and Kafka version is 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

I've written this article which explains how the integration with Kafka works:

https://bryanbende.com/development/2016/09/15/apache-nifi-and-apache-kafka

The Apache Kafka client (used by NiFi) is what assigns partitions to the consumers.

Typically if you had a 5 node NiFi cluster, with 1 ConsumeKafka processor on the canvas with 1 concurrent task, then each node would be consuming 1 partition.

Comment: Its there any way where i can run each nifi kafka consumer in all the different node as you mentioned in the your article?

Comment: It should be happening automatically, when starting the processor there is an instance on each node, and each instances creates a consumer using the Apache Kafka client which then should be auto balancing and assigning partitions, NiFi doesn't do anything special to control that part

Comment: #BryanBende we have option of selecting run consumeKafka processor on either on "all the nodes" or only in "primary node". When I selected in all nodes in my case its 3 and created 5 consumers in Nifi we get 15 instances created as I showed in the picture which is unexpected and when I choose just primary node on each Nifi consumer everything works as expected as I have topic with 5 partitions and each consumer were getting evenly distributed messages.

Comment: But as you explained each consumer was on different nodes which we can't achieved with current Nifi but all the consumer will run into just 1 node. In such case will not going to use full capacity of Nifi cluster and will alway overburden the primary node.